# Error on installing any package i.e. yfinance or finvizfinance on mac in Jupyter

Tags: yfinance

I have tried using "pip install yfinance"/"pip3 install yfinance"/"!pip install yfinance" in jupyter, but still give me error not able to install these packages.

Here is output showing after the last "Requirement already satisfied":
"Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
Building wheel for lxml (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [91 lines of output]"

"  Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
Perhaps try: xcode-select --install
*********************************************************************************
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for lxml
Running setup.py clean for lxml
Failed to build lxml
Installing collected packages: lxml, yfinance
Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Running setup.py install for lxml did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [86 lines of output]"

" Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
Perhaps try: xcode-select --install
*********************************************************************************
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lxml"

if someone can help, it would be greatly appreciated

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1):

put 'xcode-select --install' in terminal, then 'pip install yfinance'
it works!!